# Programmatically adding registration type (Entity Registration module)

Tags: 7

I am trying to programmatically add a registration type using the Entity Registration module and Drupal 7.

Currently I am using the following code:

```
$bundle = array(
    'type' => 'flake',
    'label' => $t('Flake'),
    'base' => 'registration',
    'custom' => TRUE,
);

$registration_type = registration_entity_set_default_settings($bundle);

registration_type_save($registration_type);
```

Among other thing, I have tried 'name' instead of 'label' and 'entity_registration' instead of 'registration'.

As you can probably gather, I am new to creating types of any sort. I started by working off a tutorial for creating a regular content type and did not run into any problems. Figuring out how exactly that differs from the entity registration type has been a little challenging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registration _type is just an entity type so is exactly the same as creating any other entity:

```
$registration_type = entity_create('registration_type', array(
    'name' => 'flake',
    'label' => 'Flake',
));
entity_save('registration_type', $registration_type);
```

Sometimes it helps to create an entity via the UI provided with a module and then load and inspect it to help understand what values can be provided.

For example after creating a registration type visit `/devel/php` (make sure devel module is enabled) and run this code:

```
dpm(entity_load_single('registration_type', 1));
```

You should see an output similar to this:

[image: krumo output of registration type entity]